# how to set dark theme for Material Dialog android

Tags: xml, android-layout, material-ui, android-alertdialog

dialog xml

```
 <style name="Theme.MyApp.Dialog.Alert" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/md_theme_light_onBackground</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/md_theme_light_background</item>
```

the missing attribute is the inner items color how to set it

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define dialog in your styles.xml and do whatever modifications required here.

```
<style name="MyDialog" parent="Theme.Material3.Dark.Dialog.Alert"/>
```

And then in your code

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyDialog)
```

Comment: sir i ment how to set the inner items color in Single Choice Items

Comment: @devio Sorry, I am a little confused on what exactly do you meant by inner items. So, you need text color changed or icon color changed?

Comment: i did sir , but the question itself not upvoted